# Printing a list from a random sample using join()

Tags: python

I am trying to print a python list using join after it has randomly selected a specified amount of characters. What I want is for it to print all characters beside each other instead of printing each character on a separate line. Everything works fine up until my for statement, if I print out password_letters it will print (on separate lines) the specified amount based on nr_letters. All I want is to join/concatenate the specified letters onto one line. I have followed the documentation on here and some on google, but I still can't find where I have gone wrong.

Please help me find where I have gone wrong in the below code:

```
import random

letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

nr_letters= int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n"))

password_letters = random.sample(letters, nr_letters )

for letter in password_letters:
  print("".join(letter))
```

Comment: Join `password_letters`, not each letter.

Comment: Please edit and add your desired output

Comment: @Barmar ah it works! And now that I look at it makes sense.... thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a loop, just join the list.

```
print("".join(password_letters))
```